# Angular app not loading when including ngMock

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, browserify, browserify-shim

I am using ngMock for unit testing in Angular. I now have a browserify \w Angular setup. I have some strange behaviour. When I just load angular-mocks with        `require('angular-mocks');`  my tests and app work. But if I then load it into my Angular app module as an dependency it does not load my Angular app anymore, but my karma test still works:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    require('angular');
    require('angular-route');
    require('angular-mocks');
    require('./home');

    angular.module('greenboxUi', [
        'ngRoute',
        //'ngMock',
        'greenboxUi.home'
    ]);
}());
```

If I uncomment ngMock, my app does not load anymore

My browserify-shim:

```
'angular-mocks': {
       path: './app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
       exports: 'angular.mock',
       depends: {
          angular: 'angular'
       }
 }
```

My test:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    module('greenboxUi.home');
    inject(function($controller){
        controller = $controller('HomeCtrl');
    });
});
it('test test', function() {
    expect(controller.hello).toBe('Hello world');
});
```

My app does work when just commenting 'ngMock' out, but I just find it a bit strange because the Angular docs do load it with `angular.module('app', ['ngMock'])`.. Is it because browserify wraps the module somehow?

Kind regards, Niels

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, ngMock should not be added to the dependencies of "production" project.

See this github issue for more information : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12137